# Inequality - Contour integral

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, contour-integration

I would like to solve the inequality $|\int_{\gamma} \frac{1}{z^2}dz|\leq 2$ where $\gamma$ is the line $[i,2+i]$. I thought about using the Cauchy theorem in closing the path between $i$ and $2+i$, but I don't know if this is allowed.

Is it possible to proceed in this manner? Otherwise, is anyone could give me a simple hint to solve it?

Comment: Do you know how to parametrize $\gamma$? If so, you can use $\displaystyle \int\limits_{\gamma}f(z)\text{d}z=\int\limits_{a}^{b}f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)\text{d}t$.

Comment: @Galc127 Probably in using the path $z : [0,1] \to \mathbb{C}$, $z(t) = t (i)+(1-t) (2+i)$. Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: integral $\le$ (bound of $|$integrand$|$)(length of path).

Answer (score 2):

Just use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.  If $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$ in a neighbourhood of $\gamma$, then 
$\int_\gamma f(z)\; dz = F(end
(\gamma)) - F(start(\gamma))$.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the definition of the contour integral
$$\int_\gamma f(z)dz=\int_a^bf(\alpha(t))\alpha'(t)dt$$

Where $\alpha$ is a parametrization of $\gamma$, now our curve $\gamma$ is the line segment joining $i$ and $2+i$, we can parametrize this as $\alpha(t)=t+i$, $0\leq t \leq 2$.

Then the integral is
$$
\int_0^2\frac 1 {(t+i)^2}dt=\frac {-1}{2+i}+\frac 1 {i}
$$

I'm sure you can take it from here.